# AWT или Swing

Tags: ооп, графика, awt, java, swing

Учу Яву, дошел до главы про графику. Рассматривается только awt.

1. Стоит ли читать, или сразу перейти к свинг?
2. Лучше ли свинг?
3. По каким книгам лучше учить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека Swing построена на основе базовых компонентов бибилиотеки AWT, AWT не развивается, не дорабатывается, на данный момент SWING основная графическая библа Java? AWT используют если нужна совместимость с более ранними версиями Java (например Java 1). Учите SWING!
**UPD** книги по свинг - Герберт Шилдт "Java Swing руководство для начинающих", Swing Hacks - на англише, + google

Comment: Добавлю от себя: без знания AWT вам Swing не одолеть, ибо как сказано - Swing это надстройка над AWT

Comment: 1).А если учить по Шилдту то можно?
2).Сколько прибл. времени уйдет на Swing?

Comment: Шилдт очень хорошо пишет, доступно и понятно, без нудни. Сколько времени уйдет на изучение, тут никто не скажет, все в ваших руках.

Comment: AWT несложен, его можно изучить за неделю. Swing он практически бесконечен и всеобъемлющ его можно изучать годами и не знать :) Ну если говорить о базовых понятиях Swing наверное за месяцок то можно уже привыкнуть к его идеологии.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще появилась `Java FX`, где идет построение интерфейсов на более новом, высоком и удобном уровне. Я как-то просматривал это, так мне показалось достаточно легко! Плюс еще в NetBeans достаточно удобных инструментов для визуального построения интерфейсов. Так что вперед на изучение нового!

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас найти книгу: “Swing. Руководство для начинающих” (автор: Герберт Шилдт) на бумажном носителе близко к подвигу… сам ищу, поэтому в качестве неплохой альтернативы могу порекомендовать: “Swing. Эффектные пользовательские интерфейсы” (автор: Иван Портянкин).